# can we use UI other than drools workbench to CRUD rules

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor

There is UI already there to control rules. and perform operation like CRUD using drl file or even using dsl for easing making drl rules for nontech person for such operation. So, Is there any other way to create our own webpage to control such rules for even easy usability?

Is any way to edit source codes for available workbench UI?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. Drools is open source - you can use it according to the licence. And you can always roll your own.

Comment: @laune As per example, On create new drl file, I need to integrate and trigger my java script code to trigger some database stuff.

Comment: I guess it can be programmed...? What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools is open source and you can modify the UI if you want.  You can also treat Drools like a component in your architecture by wrapping it in a service and calling it through your own simplified API.  You can then call your API from your own web front end.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me to dig more into drools.